# Laravel 4.2 dynamic database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am trying to setup connections to multiple database under the same instance for correlation data analysis

Here is the basic idea of the connection code

```
    $a = array('a','b','c');
    $b = array('a','b','c');

    foreach($a as $ac){
        foreach($b as $bc){     
            Config::set('database.connections.'.$ac.'_'.$bc, array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'somehost',
                'port'      => '3306',
                'database'  => $ac.'_'.$bc,
                'username'  => 'user',
                'password'  => 'user',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => ''
            ));
        }
    }
```

There are about 40 different db in that instance, and could change rapidly, so I want to avoid permanently create the connection in the config file and generate the connection on the fly with user input. And from what I gather, the above code should auto append the array to database.connections (see [laravel github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1849) ), but I am getting this error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

if I change `database.connections.".$ac.'_'.$bc` to `database.connections.mysql` the code runs okay. So what am I missing here :( , I am calling that piece of code under the constructor of the first controller the input will hit.

Thank you very much for the help in advance

Comment: hi. did u find your answer?

Comment: check my comment below. It's been a while since I touch the code for that project, but based on the observation I found, I create a dummy table in every new DB I bringing up, so the code always have something to point to guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit, found out what's the problem.
After calling the code above in controller,
in model, not only you have to make the initial connection but also you have to include a table in that statement in order to divert the connection to the specific DB, otherwise it will fall back to default connection if you use the way that builder query example from Laravel documentation. So instead of doing

```
$this->query = DB::connection($ac.'_'.$bc);
$this->query = DB::table('sometable');
```

do it like

```
$this->query = DB:connection($ac.'_'.$bc)->table('sometable');
```

Then connection for $this->query will lock to the new database pointed.